# QPainter::drawLine and QPainter::drawText with different color issue in Qt

Tags: qt

I am facing problem for drawing line and text with different color using QPainter. I am using the following piece of code to achieve this but it's not working. Both lines and texts are drawn using the color set for drawing Text.

```
void MyWidget::drawHorLinesWithText(QPainter & painter, const QRect & rect)
{  
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        QPen penHLines(QColor("#0e5a77"), 1, Qt::DotLine, Qt::FlatCap, Qt::RoundJoin);
        painter.setPen(penHLines);
        painter.drawLine(10, 50 - (5*(i+1)), 200, 50 - (5*(i+1)));

        QString strNumber = QString::number((2)*(i+1));

        painter.setFont(QFont("Arial", 8, QFont::Bold));
        //QBrush brush(QColor("#00e0fc"));
        //painter.setBrush(brush);
        QPen penHText(QColor("#00e0fc"));//Here lines are also drawn using this color
        painter.setPen(penHText);
        painter.drawText(5, 50 - (5*(i+1)) - 10), 20, 30, Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter,
                         strNumber);
    }
}
```

How would I set different colors for drawing lines and Texts. Any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: In your first call to setPen(), you don't use the pen created just above. Is it a typo that was added when you copy/pasted here ? There is also an extra parenthesis in your last drawText()

Comment: why recreating `QPen`s at each iteration?

Comment: Hi triclosan, I want to set different colors for drawing lines and drawing texts separately.

Comment: I downvoted the question because you didn't put any effort into ensuring that it actually compiles, which actually affects how much we can help you and typically wastes everyone's time.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me with Qt 5.3; perhaps it was a bug in the version you were using?

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
public:
    Widget() {
        resize(200, 200);
    }

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
        QPainter painter(this);
        for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            QPen penHLines(QColor("#0e5a77"), 10, Qt::DotLine, Qt::FlatCap, Qt::RoundJoin);
            painter.setPen(penHLines);
            painter.drawLine(10, 50 - (5*(i+1)), 200, 50 - (5*(i+1)));

            QString strNumber = QString::number((2)*(i+1));

            painter.setFont(QFont("Arial", 8, QFont::Bold));
            QPen penHText(QColor("#00e0fc"));
            painter.setPen(penHText);
            painter.drawText(5, 50 - (5*(i+1)) - 10, 20, 30, Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter, strNumber);
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I increased the line width to 10 to see what's going on:

[image: qpainter]

Answer (score 0):

QPainter draw text using QBrush, not QPen. Text is rendered with glyph strokes then filled with current brush. Current pen only controls lines and strokes.

Comment: I already tried with QBrush. But same result. Please check my posted code. I commented out the QBrush as it's not working in my case.

Comment: According to the doc : [QPainter::setPen()](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#setPen) "The pen defines how to draw lines and outlines, and it also defines the text color."

Comment: As mentioned in my code I tried with QBrush and QPen, but result is the same. Am I missing anything? Please guide me if I am doing anything wrong.